# Prevent battery "damages"

Tags: android, power-management

I'm currently developing with Android SDK, and because I'm building an application based on camera, I cannot use the emulator to test it.

This means that the following scenario happens quite frequently

- I connect my phone to USB the battery is 50%
- I disconnect it before it is fully charged, e.g. 80%
- I have to leave, and I want to take my phone with me
- I come back and connect again and so on...

I read that Lithium-ion batteries don't suffer the memory effect, but, on the other hand, I also read that one should wait until the battery is fully charged before disconnecting it from the USB.

So, I'm wondering if the way I'm using the phone now for debugging may damage or reduce the life of my battery

Any advice is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I'm not an expert in this subject.

Lithium-ion battery, as you say, does not suffer the charge memory effect but they have the "digital memory" (affects the accuracy % remaining battery) as reflected in this article (so you have to fully-discharge - fully-charge periodically the battery to avoid this):

Source: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/five-tips/five-tips-for-extending-lithium-ion-battery-life/289

More info about it:

*"Partial discharge on Li-ion is fine; there is no memory and the battery does not need periodic full discharge cycles other than to calibrate the fuel gauge on a smart battery"*

So partial discharge is not a problem. *The worst condition is keeping a fully charged battery at elevated temperatures*

Source: http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_prolong_lithium_based_batteries

About the need to fully-charge in Lithium-ion batteries, I did find a source about it, but in Apple support you can find this:

*"You can disconnect and use your iPod before the battery is fully charged. You don't have to wait until the battery is completely empty before charging it again. This is because lithium-ion batteries, such as those used in iPod, have none of the memory effects seen in nickel-based rechargeable batteries"*

Source: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1384

Conclusion: Your partial charges/discharges won't be noticeable. If you want to extend the battery life, follow the suggestions you can find in the first two articles (avoid hot, don't let fully discharge... etc).

Comment: Hi jBilbo thank you very much for your accurate answer and also for adding source articles. I'll definitely read them carefully.